# Crypto policy unlimited ignored by JBoss

Tags: java, jboss, jce, jasypt

While trying to encrypt some data using jasypt, I run across the exception below:

```
org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException: Encryption raised an exception. A possible cause is you are using strong encryption algorithms and you have not installed the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files in this Java Virtual Machine
```

I found a couple of questions so I fixed the issue by setting the crypto.policy property to unlimited in my code:

```
Security.setProperty("crypto.policy", "unlimited");
```

I deployed the war in a JBoss in my machine, and it works. But then we tried to install it in a different environment (not managed entirely by us), and it seems to somehow ignore the property (I have some logs to show its value, and I can see that the value is ok right before the encryption), because we're still getting the same error.

So, my question is: what can possibly be configured in JBoss to get that property ignored, even when changed programmatically?

We've checked the Java version in that environment and it's `"1.8.0_152"`, so we think it should be ok. What are we missing?

Answer (score 1):

what error you are getting? if you are getting the exception mentioned above that may be due to the fact that you haven't installed  [Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html) in the new environment. You can check what JCE in your machine and in the new environment.

Comment: The error is already in the question, it says that you need to install JCE in the machine. The thing is that according to [Java 8u151 release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u151-relnotes-3850493.html): "The download and install steps are no longer necessary". That's why I did it programmatically just by setting the property, and it worked in a couple of machines without installing anything, till we bumped into that machine where it doesn't.

Comment: I am having same problem with JDK 1.8. Were you able to fix the issue?